# Using sequelize distinct option correctly (on postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use the distinct clause to filter out some rows from a query. I have two models called Parcel and DeliveryProblem. Each parcel can have **n** delivery problems and I **must**  get a list of Parcels through the DeliveryProblem side of the relation.

Obviously this causes the result to have many duplicated Parcels which I'd like to filter out. This is what I have tried using:

```
const problems = await DeliveryProblem.findAll({
   limit: 20,
   offset: (page - 1) * 20,
   attributes: ['parcel_id', 'id'],
   include: [
     {
       model: Parcel,
       as: 'parcel',
       distinct: ['parcel_id']
       attributes: ['product', 'start_date'],
       include: [
         {
           model: Deliveryman,
           as: 'deliveryman',
           attributes: ['name'],
         },
       ],
     },
   ],
 });
```

It seems sequelize simply ignores the distinct property and keeps returning me the full set. Is there any other way to achieve the distinct set of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **distinct** option with **count** and **aggregate** functions only.

Comment: I see...so the other option I came up with in this case is to use a raw query instead. I'm just wondering if this is the best way to go. Doesn't sequelize provide any way to do a simple distinct without having to aggregate?

Comment: the distinct operator is an aggregate function itself.A complex aggregation should be done by plain SQL.

Comment: I agree with you, but since what I'm trying to do is something so simple (have distinct rows based on the foreign key field parcel_id) I thought sequelize would be able to deal with this "natively". Anyways, guess I'll stick with a raw query then. Thanks!